# chkdsk not logged to even log on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, chkdsk

If I schedule chkdsk to run on restart:

```
chkdsk C: /F /X
```

No results are reported in event log after chkdsk is run (used `Ctrl-F` -> `chkdsk` to find it).

Is anyone else seeing this ?

**UPDATE**
It seems there are text log files in `C:\System Volume Information\Chkdsk*.log` - did they stop moving them to Event log ? All resources on the web say that chkdsk will be recorded in event log under wininit process.

Comment: Mine showed as event id 1001 (Wininit) in Event Viewer>Windows Logs>Application

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested the same method as you and reviewed results. If I open `Event Viewer` and navigate to `Windows Logs` > `Applications` I can find the desired results.

The event ID I received was `26213` and `26212`. Following this, I was able to run a standard custom filter:

I cannot post an image. I would imagine you can make a custom filter by yourself anyway to prove this. It may be benefitial to see if the logs have anything to do with the above EventID's or you may need to search for a list of ID's (the parameters are logged with different ID's I believe)

Here is a powershell script you can run to locate the file, then paste it to your desktop.

```
get-winevent -FilterHashTable @{logname="Application"; id="26212"}| ?{$_.providername –match "CHKDSK"} | fl timecreated, message | out-file Desktop\CHKDSKResults.txt
```

I can confirm that the source is not `wininit` anymore, but `Chkdsk` itself.

Let me know if I have covered everything. I am sure someone here will correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `get-winevent : No events were found that match the specified selection criteria`. Weird.

Comment: This is because it searching for an event ID of 26212. Open up your event viewer and find CHKDSK. Alternatively just remove the parameter to search by event ID.

Comment: I tried searching for `chkdsk` in the beginning (see above).

Comment: @MarcinWisnicki What OS are you running? Also, scheduling may be logged in a different matter. This would be something to look into. Unfortunately I've just tried on 4 Windows PC and am able to find it. I'll come back to this once I have an update.

Comment: The name of the OS is in the subject of the posting and in tags :)

Comment: @MarcinWisnicki Ignore my stupidity :)

Answer (score 1):

chkdsk C: /F /X

Its still wininit on my W10 PC, event id 1001

[image]

Answer (score 0):

solution, which worked for me:

clear ALL Windows-event logs,
run chkdsk again,
wininit throws its message again into event log.

cheers